# Restrict Azure WebJobs to RUN on Week Ends and Holidays

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

How can I configure Azure web job to run only in Week Days?
I do not want to RUN the Azure web job on week ends (Saturday, Sunday) and Holidays.

We can schedule azure web job to RUN in week days by CRON expression but how to restrict it to RUN in holidays, I am not sure.

Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: At the beginning you say you do not want to RUN the Azure web job on week ends (Saturday, Sunday) and Holidays then you want to know how to restrict it to RUN in holidays. What's your real requirement, maybe you could provide some sample.

Comment: I have written like that, I want to RUN web job only in week days but not in week end and holidays.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean public holidays which cron won't be able to do so you probably need to write an intermediate program and call that from the cron, or have an app setting with a list of dates that you update yearly for public holidays and then your web job will check the day and not run if it's a public holiday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your replies

Actually, the web job which we have deployed at Azure is related to Microsoft Dynamics 365, Hence, we have used Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Closure Days functionality to identify the holidays and have written code in our hosted .Net Application program.

Answer (score 1):

As Simon said, public holidays which cron will not be able to set up. So you could write a intermediate program to invoke the webjob.

Set app setting in program with a list of dates that you update yearly for public holidays and then your program will check the day and not run if it's a public holiday.